# jQuery keydown event event data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, keydown

I am in the process of upgrading our application's jQuery version from 1.4.2.
I have a chunk of JS, which I don't see why it would work but in fact works in 1.4.2 and not in 1.4.3+

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'f3',
           function (event) {
               alert("f3");
               //Do something
});
```

**in jQuery 1.4.2 this WORKS and triggers the event handler only for F3.**
When I upgrade to 1.4.3+ the event handler is triggered for any `keydown` (which I think makes sense).

Does the `keydown` event know to use the event data and check if the key was pressed?

Can anyone help me clarify if it does or does not, and if not why would this code be working in jQuery 1.4.2?
I checked the release notes and the only thing that changed is added method signatures for the bind and `keydown` events.

Comment: I don't think that would ever work in any version of jQuery, if "work" means "intercepts presses of the F3 key".

Comment: Yes, it DEFINITELY works and I don't understand why it would :)

Comment: Um, were you using a 3rd party plugin like hot keys?

Comment: nope, really plain plain jQuery and js...

Comment: The `.bind()` API has been stable since version 1.0 of jQuery, and the second argument in the three-argument version has always been for data to be passed in to the event handler. Now, if the event handler in question here used that data as the indicator of what keycode to filter, then that would work, but the library has never done that implicitly.

Comment: just for the future if anyone sees the question - my code was in fact using a (helpful) thirdparty script which handles this kind of call - I er-added the code and everything worked, thanks to those who tried to help

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The event object has all information regarding event. But you need to check for F3 manually using properties such as `keyCode` and `which` and such properties.

For example the keyCode for F3 is 114. So you would check it like this:

```
if(e.keyCode === 114){
  //F3 is pressed
}
```

### It might be working for you still because now, the second(optional) argument is `eventData` to which you're passing `'f3'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes that is true, my question is that this is code which was not written by me and happens to work in 1.4.2 - when F3 is pressed the correct event handler is triggered, so I am wondering WHY this was working till now?

Comment: @NinaNa check out my lastline

Comment: So does the keydown event know to 'automatically' take the event data and interpret it as the key to compare to the event.which?

Comment: @NinaNa it has values related to the event and you've to compare it to your convenience.

Comment: I understand that, but the thing is that I DON'T compare it and it WORKS in jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: @NinaNa do you use it now? If yes then don't compare but if you want to use latest versions, you'll have to learn it..

Comment: the code is exactly how I posted it above, there's is an additional line that does a certain focus. but I do not check. to fix the issue I WILL obviously add the condition but I am wondering why it worked before I upgraded? What changed in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check for the key property and you should be doing it as follows:

```js
$(document).keydown(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 114 ) { // 114 is the identifier for F3
    //Do some stuff
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```